# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'ControladorPlantilla' not found in

Tags: php, html

Tengo un archivo HTML donde estoy colocando un formulario, para ello, necesito colocar código PHP por sus funciones, pero tal parece que mi archivo HTML no me permite colocarlas pero desconozco si estoy haciendo mal.

Adjunto mi código HTML y en el aparece un pequeño código PHP que es el que no me funciona:

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return validarContactenos()">
  <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
           <input type="text" id="nombreContactenos" name="nombreContactenos" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombres y Apellidos" />
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
          <input type="email" id="emailContactenos" name="emailContactenos" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" />
      </div>
 </div>
                           
 <div class="form-group">
      <textarea id="mensajeContactenos" name="mensajeContactenos" class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Mensaje"></textarea>
 </div>
                            
 <div class="text-center">
      <button type="submit">Enviar mensaje</button>
 </div>

 <?php

    $contactenos = new ControladorPlantilla();
    $contactenos -> ctrFormularioContactenos();

 ?>

</form>
```

Y esto es lo que me aparece en pantalla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y así se ve en mi código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código en donde vinculo las funciones...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y dentro de la funcion `ctrFormularioContactenos()` he colocado las validaciones y el uso de PHP MAILER y alertas de SweetAlert2

Comment: Saludos. (Tiene años que no uso PHP); prueba quitando los espacios que estan en ` $contactenos -> ctrFormularioContactenos();` tal que, quede ` $contactenos->ctrFormularioContactenos();`; la verdad se me hace raro.

Comment: Hola Roberto, ya lo he intentado pero sigue igual =(

Comment: Te diría que actives los errores de php, error_reporting(E_ALL);
Tiene que haber algun error que no te está informando.
Por lo que veo las etiquetas <?php las tenes habilitadas.

Comment: Lo estaba tratando de ejecutar con extensión .html y si estoy usando XAMPP

Comment: @MayraXimenaVargas para que el servidor "identifique" tu página es dinámica (en este caso una PHP) debe tener extensión PHP.

Comment: La había intentado poner con extensión .PHP, sin embargo si hacia esto y colocaba el código php se me borra todo el formulario

Comment: te queda el sitio en blanco? o se borra solo el formulario?

Comment: Se quedaba en blanco, quite unos elementos del html y ya se muestra, pero ahora no me muestra este error: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'ControladorPlantilla' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\nuevo-qfsmex\contactanos.php:209 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\nuevo-qfsmex\contactanos.php on line 209` pero desconozco porque, si son exactos los nombres que ocupe para sus funciones =(

Comment: De mi ahora archivo .php si, pero lo actualizo para colocar como se ven las funciones ...

Comment: Ya lo he actualizado =(

Comment: Hola. Por lo que se ve en la imagen tu php crea las variables pero, no envía valores al formulario a no ser que dentro del método ctrFormularioContectenos() exista una sentencia echo o print o algo que vuelque un valor al buffer de salida.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No puedes establecer una instancia de una clase en un archivo que *no conoce de dicha clase* (.

Dicho lo anterior, para poder usar a la clase **`ControladorPlantilla`** debes importarla a tu archivo *contactanos.php* de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php

require_once 'ruta/de/tu/archivo.php';

$objetoNuevo = new Clase();

?>
```

Entonces:

- Deberás colocar dentro de las etiquetas de apertura y cierre de PHP el llamado al archivo por medio de [**`require_once`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.require-once.php) o [**`require`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.require.php) según sea el caso
- Importante: el llamado al archivo debe ocurrir justo antes de que haces la *instancia*

Quedando así:

```
<?php
    require_once 'rutadelarchivo/ControladorPlantilla.php';     

    $contactenos = new ControladorPlantilla();
    $contactenos -> ctrFormularioContactenos();

 ?>
```

Comment: adicionalmente debe hacer algo como `echo $contactenos->ctrFormularioContactenos();`

Comment: @quevedo cierto aunque no logro ver exactamente que hace dicho método, pero es bueno se haga la aclaración

Comment: Imagino que devuelva un bloque html como cadena. De ahí que sugiera volcarlo, a no ser que devuelva una clase que tenga método mágico __toString() que no creo que sea el caso

Comment: si @quevedo le he dejado un comentario a la OP para que agregue detalles sobre el mismo y en consecuencia poder editar

Comment: Muchas gracias si me funciono, si quise agregar el código pero no me deja publicarlo ya que me dice que es bastante, en la función venían validaciones y alertas con sweetalert2, ya lo he probado y ya me funciono gracias a ustedes, ahora solo tengo que averiguar porque no me limpia los campos después de enviar la información del formulario je